# Python Flask - How to use SubmitField to delete object?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm a bit confused as how to have a "Delete" button on a page that will delete the object currently in focus.

I'm trying to add this button to /edit/ to delete whichever id is open

Using Python3 and Flask

forms.py

```
class EditForm(Form):
  name = StringField('Server Name', validators = [Length(1, 120), DataRequired()])
  ip_address = StringField('IP Address', validators = [Length(1, 16), IPAddress()])
  username = StringField('UCX User', validators = [Length(1, 64)])
  password = StringField('UCX Password', validators = [Length(1, 64)])
  description = StringField('Purpose/Description', validators = [Length(1-120)])
  protocol = RadioField('Protocol', [DataRequired()],
           choices=[('https', 'HTTPS'), ('http', 'HTTP')], default='https')

  submit = SubmitField('Submit')
  **delete = SubmitField('Delete')**
```

Routes.py

```
@servers.route('/edit/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])    
def edit(id):
  server = UcxServer.query.filter_by(id=int(id)).first_or_404()
  form = EditForm(obj=server)
  if form.validate_on_submit():
      form.to_model(server)
      db.session.commit()
      flash('Your changes have been saved.')

  return render_template('addserver2.html', form=form)
```

Routes.py delete function:

```
@servers.route('/delete/<id>')
def delete(id):

server = UcxServer.query.filter_by(id=int(id)).first_or_404()
try:
  db.session.delete(server)
  db.session.commit()
  flash('Successfully deleted the {} server'.format(server))
  return redirect(url_for('servers.index'))
```

Template (addserver2.html):

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
<h1>UCX Server</h1>
</div>
{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

So basically, I can load the edit/ page, but how do I hook up the "Delete" SubmitField to call the /delete/?

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. Posting answer for future folks.
Not sure if best way, but only took 2 lines of code:

For the /edit/ route, I simply added this check.

```
if form.delete.data:

    return redirect(url_for('servers.delete', id=id))
```

Which makes the entire edit route look like this:

```
def edit(id):
  server = UcxServer.query.filter_by(id=int(id)).first_or_404()
  form = EditForm(obj=server)
  if form.delete.data:

    return redirect(url_for('servers.delete', id=id))

  if form.validate_on_submit():
    form.to_model(server)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('Your changes have been saved.')

  return render_template('addserver2.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use customized validators. Like this:

```
delete = SubmitField('Delete', validators=delete())
```

About how to make a function a customized validator, check this [link](https://exploreflask.com/forms.html). The custom validators section.

Comment: I read the entire page you linked. I am still not sure how to accomplish what I need. 

The example given in the example checks to see if the email address provided to the form is unique.

Are you suggesting that I create a new validator, that when called actually performs the delete?

Comment: @Balrizangor If you hook up the 'Delete' SubmitField with delete function, it will be invoked every time when this filed gets called. Right?

Comment: Just so that I do not misunderstand you:

You're saying create a custom validator which calls my @server.delete function?

So i'd have a validator which gets passed in the <id>, calls the delete/<id> function, and that's all?